# event listener resize window not working on first expand only

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make the side buttons in the carousel(3rd slide) change based on the inner slide container size resizing with media query. I've got it working except for one bug. When I resize back from smaller responsive, the button doesn't change, until I resize again (smaller or bigger but on the same media query)

- Site to reproduce error: https://9wk9h.csb.app/
- The Full Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/my-portfolio-2021-9wk9h

This is the block of code used in the file src/Components/AboutComponents/AboutCarousel.js:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (slideIndex === slideIndexes.fun) {
      const handleResize = debounce(() => {
        setIsScreenResized(!isScreenResized);
        console.log('isScreenResized changed =', isScreenResized);
        console.log('---------------------')
      }, 100);

      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize, false);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize, false);
      }
    }
  },[slideIndex, slideIndexes, hobbyTabIdSelected, isScreenResized, setIsScreenResized]);
```

See the following use case below to reproduce the issue:

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I'm getting faChevronUp when expanding. Still need help on this ?

Comment: What is `isMoviesScreenResized` used for ?

Comment: Seems like work [screenshoot](https://ibb.co/0GLmd5Q) (chrome)

Comment: The first it's not a bug, As you can see button change when you come to the last section where is "George Callin", when you resize you will see content will re-rendering to first "tab" so the button is correct

Comment: The second video is same issue, when you resize the content will go down so it's all correct.

Comment: I found the issue, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the transition had a timout of 1 second set in the index.css for `all` which would include the height resize(being read by the eventListener):

```
.div-about-carousel-slide-container {
  ...
  transition: all 1000ms ease-in-out; /* double size of about-carousel-slide-hide */
}
```

Therefor the content list would not complete the resize until after 1 second, and the debouncer was set to 0.1second (to read before the content resized).

**The Fix:**

Since we want to keep slide transition to keep the opacity flash, we change it to the following:

```
.div-about-carousel-slide-container {
  ...
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in-out; /* double size of about-carousel-slide-hide */
}
```

(Note: I'm probably going to refer to this question in the feature on why setting `transition` to `all` is a bad default habbit)